# PATCH request doesn't seem to reach Express.js server

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, fiddler

I'm writing (as an exercise) an Express + React application that manages a To Do list. You can see the code [on GitHub](https://github.com/roninbar/2020-08-18-todo/tree/stackoverflow).

Each task has a Done button that sends a PATCH request to the server. However, when I press it I get a `400 Bad Request`.

Furthermore,

1. Even though the server is configured to log every request, these PATCH requests don't appear in the log output.
2. When Fiddler is running, the PATCH requests suddenly begin to work just fine! As soon as I close Fiddler, I start to get 400 again.

The same behavior is observed in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause: I spelled `patch` in lowercase. Apparently, Express only recognizes `PATCH` in uppercase.

Strangely enough, this idiosyncrasy doesn't apply to other methods like `post` and `delete`, which are recognized also in lowercase.

Fiddler probably converts all method names to uppercase before forwarding the requests to the server.